# UPDATE in PostgreSQL generates same UUID

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, uuid

I have added new `uuid` column for one of my tables and installed `uuid-ossp` extension.
Now I want to update all existing records and set value for this new `uuid` column.

I do not want to use DEFAULT fallback for ADD COLUMN, but rather I want to do it in UPDATE statement, so I have something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET uuid = (SELECT uuid_generate_v4());
```

but the issue I have is that same UUID is generated for all records.

Is there a way to pass seed value or something to generate function or another way to enforce generated UUIDs to be unique?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try modifying the UUID subquery such that it forces/tricks Postgres into generating a new UUID for each record:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET uuid = uuid_generate_v4()
WHERE uuid IS NOT NULL;
```

The `WHERE` clause is just a dummy, but perhaps will result in Postgres calling the UUID function once for each record.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out all I had to do was remove "SELECT" from subquery. I guess it does some caching or something like that?

Comment: @whatamidoingwithmylife Correct.  Postgres thinks it's helping you by realizing that it can just execute the non correlated subquery once, then caching and reusing the result.  Except that in your case, you actually don't want that behavior.

Comment: UPDATE table_name SET uuid = uuid_generate_v4() without the WHERE clause did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you call the `uuid_generate_v4()` function in a subquery, PostgreSQL will assume that the subquery needs to be called only once, since it does not contain any reference to the surrounding query. Consequently, all rows will be updated to the same `uuid`, which fails.

If you remove the subquery and leave only the function call, the function is called for each row, since it is `VOLATILE`.