# Postegresql: update all rows in table setting STRING column to new UUID?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I am trying to do what I see in this question:

[UPDATE in PostgreSQL generates same UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65991377/update-in-postgresql-generates-same-uuid)

I have a `car` table with a STRING column named `uuid`. `uuid` is unique, so each row needs a different value set.

I want to set a new uuid on all `car` rows, and so I tried this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET uuid = uuid_generate_v4();
```

However, when I run that I get this ERROR:

```
[42883] ERROR: function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So, I thought the `uuid_generate_v4()` function was something available within Postgres but I am obviously wrong.

How can I fix the error? How can I declare I function I can call in the update call so that a new unique uuid is generate and set in each row into `uuid`?

Comment: `uuid_generate_v4()` is provided by the extension [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) - did you install that? If you are on Postgres 13 or newer you don't need it, you can use the built-in [gen_random_uuid ](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) instead

Comment: I see. I'm on 12.11 unfortunately. As I looked into the requirements I actually will need uuid v5. I'll check the extension option you mentioned and see. Thanks